# A very simple question about convexity of a bond

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields, convexity

I was always under the impression that, ceteris paribus, higher the coupon rate, higher the convexity of the bond.

[image]

But [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/convexity.asp) says the following:

*"zero-coupon bonds have the highest degree of convexity"*.

Isn't that wrong?

Please correct me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chart you posted does not give a correct visual representaion of convexity . Convexity is not $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}$ but $\frac{1}{P}\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2}$. So you have to normalize for P. The 4 curves you plot have very different P.

When the curves are redrawn normalized so they go through the same point $(y_0,P_0)$ you will see that smaller coupons have bigger convexity. And zero coupons the biggest of all.

Put differently: convexity is measured "per dollar invested" not "per bond".